# Interpreting gfortran error traceback

Tags: linux, bash, debugging, fortran, gfortran

I'm running a Fortran 77 program written by someone else. I'm using the gfortran compiler (v5.4.0) on Linux (Ubuntu v.16.04). I'm not an experienced user of Fortran, gcc or bash scripting, so I'm struggling here.

When my program finishes running, I get the following message:

`Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL`

I had to look this up - I understand that some of my floating-point numbers need to be stored "denormal", a low-precision form for very small numbers (rather than flushing them to zero). These come from the unstable aerodynamic calculations in the program - I've seen this when doing the calculations longhand. It's unlikely that these denormal quantities are significantly affecting my results, but to try and find out where/why this was happening, I tried compiling with the following error options:

`gfortran –g –fbacktrace –ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,denormal –O3 –mcmodel=medium –o ../program.exe`

The program compiled, but at runtime it crashed and returned:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F442F143E08
#1  0x7F442F142F90
#2  0x7F442EA8A4AF
#3  0x4428CF in subroutine2_ at code.f:3601 (discriminator 3)
#4  0x442C3F in subroutine1_ at code.f:3569
#5  0x4489DA in code_ at code.f:428
#6  0x42BdD1 in MAIN__ at main.f:235
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I can interpret these as a hierarchy of calls, working backwards from 6 to 3:

*6. At line 235 of "main.f", there was a problem. [this is a call to "code.f"]

*5. At line 428 of "code.f", there was a problem. [this is a call to "subroutine1" in "code.f"]

*4. At line 3569 of "code.f", in "subroutine1", there was a problem. [this is a call to "subroutine2" in "code.f"]

*3. At line 3601 of "code.f", in "subroutine2", there was a problem. [this is a conditional statement]

`if (windspd_2m.ge.5.0) then...`

So the DENORMAL error must be occurring in the "then" operations (I haven't included that code because (a) it involves a long, complicated series of dependencies, and (b) I can unravel the math errors, it's the debug errors I'm struggling with).

But for the above errors 2,1,0... I don't know how to interpret these strings of numbers/letters. I also don't know what "discriminator 3" means. I've googled these, but the only resources I've found explain them assuming a higher level of knowledge than I have. Can anyone help me to interpret these error codes, assuming very little pre-existing knowledge of Fortran, gcc, or bash scripting?

Comment: You are on the right track. Your program crashes because you told it to crash on floating point exceptions with `-ffpe-trap=...`. The top three stack frames are most likely calls to libraries or intrinsic functions that deal with the actual error handling. I wouldn't worry too much about those.

Comment: OK, thanks @chw21! It sounds like going into the source code and finding the source of the denom is the best way to deal with this. There's a chance that it's reasonable to leave the denom numbers in the calculations, depending on where they are. I'll look more into control of `-ffpe-trap` - it would be better if I could make it generate a warning instead of crashing the program.

Comment: *edit: "denom" should be "denormal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three stack frames are due to the implementation of backtracing in the GFortran runtime library (libgfortran). The backtrace can't resolve addresses in dynamic libraries symbolically, hence you get just the addresses. If you want to see symbolic output, you can add "-static" to your compile options.

Thus my first guess would be that the error is at code.f:3601, and since 5.0 is a constant it follows that windspd_2m ought to be denormal.

Comment: Hi @janneb, thanks! I don't know what a dynamic library is, so I'll go find out. And I'll try the -static option right now.

For the error at code.f:3601, your conclusion makes sense, but windpsd_2m is drawn directly from a weather time series, which contains no denormal values. Because it's a condition, I think the error is in the "then" statements, which I summarized in my post as "...", since that block is fairly large. I wondered if that's what the backtrace meant by "discriminator 3"... somehow indicating which part of the "then" block was signaling... does that make sense?

Comment: OK, I've done my homework on static vs dynamic linking - seems important, glad I'm adding it to my knowledge base. Incorporating "-static" at compilation does return symbolic output for those 3 frames. However, the output doesn't yield new information, because these frames are calls to gsignal, the gfortran backtrace handler, and the gfortran backtrace itself.

So, the error must be somewhere within the conditional statement starting at code.f:3601. Time to check my math!